# Node.js Async/Promise explanation with JIMP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord bot that takes an uploaded picture attachment, saves it to a temporary file after editing, and then uploads it to the Discord server. Everything works, except for the timing. The `sendImage` function gets called after the `generateImagePixel` function, but tries to upload the temp image before `jimp.write` is finished, causing an ENOENT error. How would I fix my timing issue?

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.includes(config.prefix + 'pixel')) {
        var tempname = d.getTime();
        console.log(tempname);
        generateImagePixel(message.attachments, tempname).then(() => sendImage(tempname, message))
    }
});

function generateImagePixel(msg, name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        msg.forEach(a => {
            try {
                jimp.read(a.url, function (err, image) {
                    const clone = image.clone();
                    clone.pixelate(8)
                    .rgba(true)
                    .filterType(0)         
                    .write('./temp/' + name + '.png');
                });
            } catch(err) {
                 console.log(err);
            }
        });
        resolve(name)
    })
}

function sendImage(tempname, msg) {
    msg.channel.send({
        file: './temp/'+ tempname + '.png' // Or replace with FileOptions object
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typical example of executing asynchronous functions in a synchronous loop.

`jimp.read` is asycnhronous, so each call returns immediately before the actual stuff it does finishes. Therefore `msg.forEach` also finishes before `jimp` is done.

Once you are using something asynchronous, all you do has to be in asynchronous style:

```
function generateImagePixel(msg, name) {
  const promises = msg.map(attachment => {
    return jimp.read(attachment.url)
      .then(image => {
        return image
          .pixelate(8)
          .rgba(true)
          .filterType(0)         
          .write('./temp/' + name + '.png');
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  });

  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => name);
}
```